# Seat Ibiza Power steering doesn’t work on first turn over every time

Tags: steering, power

It doesn’t happen every time but sometimes when I start my car the power steering light comes up saying it has failed and then all I do it turn it off and turn it back on and the power steering works again, does anyone have any idea why it’s happening? And is it a long term problem? And how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site.. what year and model is your Ibiza?

Comment: Hi, it’s a 2003 5 door petrol seat ibiza

Comment: Slight googling reveals it's an electro-hydraulic power steering system.

Comment: First thing to check would be the power steering fluid. It should be in a separate reservoir on the front left (underneath the battery, may need to remove it).

Comment: @Daniel Unlikely to be fluid-related - the light doesn't come on for fluid level

Comment: @motosubatsu I am pretty shure there is no seperate light for servo-fluid levle.

Comment: @Daniel there isn't - but fluid level alone doesn't trigger that light on a Mk3 Ibiza, it's a "I think there's something wrong with the pump" light not a fluid level light

Comment: @motosubatsu: How do you think a servo pump running with insufficient fluid reacts?

Comment: @Daniel Generally not well - usually noisily and with poor steering performance (been there done that on a few cars), in theory if it ran with either such a severe lack of fluid or for a long enough period of time so as to damage the pump and prevent it running you'd get the light. But the other symptoms would be apparent and prominent before it got to that stage - it's **not** a fluid level warning light on these cars. They don't have a sensor to tell that. And FWIW I've never seen a Mk3 Ibiza where the fluid level was the cause of that light appearing.

Comment: @Daniel No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Typically the first port of call for this on the Mk3 Ibiza is actually the battery - the Power Assisted Steering (PAS) pump is quite a big draw on these and they can throw the light for this. If you battery is old or otherwise showing signs of weakness that would be a good place to start.

The fact that it seems to clear on a quick restart leans me against this in your case though - the battery is going to be *weaker* the second time around as unless you've driven it a bit the alternator won't have had time to replenish the initial effort of starting.

A known fault on these that causes the PAS light to be lit is the 50A fuse for the PAS pump - they have a tendency to crack which causes an intermittent connection and this leads to the light.

If neither of these things then it might be the pump itself - they are electric and sometimes suffer from water ingress at the connectors causing intermittent electrical faults.

Another possibility is the steering angle sensor, an outside bet though.

Comment: Perhaps with this in mind, a good first step would be to put the battery on charge overnight to see if that stops the fault at first startup in the morning.

Comment: @SteveMatthews Agreed!

Comment: Okie dokie, thank you all for your advise, I’ll put my battery on charge tomorrow day when I get home from work and will see how out goes after re-connecting that night  will update with result 

Comment: Nope the battery didn’t work so I’ll try changing the fuse yes? 

Comment: @CharlotteHardy Yeah fuse would probably be my next step.